# Master Service Agreement templates in Japanese?

Tags: legal-writing, japan

My company has started doing business with several Japanese clients and we are moving beyond a letter of intent to a master service agreement. We have a standard template we use for all of our clients; however, it's currently in english. I don't want to pay to have it translated into Japanese.

I'm wondering if there are MSA templates in Japanese? A more abstract question is are there common repositories for legal documents in different languages?

Here is an example MSA: http://www.jdsupra.com/legalnews/information-technology-master-service-ag-84601/

Comment: If you don't want to pay for translation in either direction, then how will you know what you're signing?

Comment: We have a japanese lawyer on our side, we just don't want to pay 300/hr to translate a full document. Instead we want to have him read and modify an existing template. Most business legal work starts with a template

Comment: OK, just wanted to check you weren't just relying on a template!

Comment: Fair enough. It's a reasonable concern

Comment: @CharlesHoskinson, Actually you might have better luck asking this on http://quora.com

Comment: I asked on both websites at the same time. If I get an answer there, then I'll post here

Answer (score 2):

Japanese Government (METI) has released model (sample) Master Service Agreements for IT industries.  Yes, these are written in Japanese.

For details, click the link below or google "情報システム・モデル取引・契約書".
http://www.meti.go.jp/policy/it_policy/softseibi/index.html#05

There are a several version of model MSAs (e.g. for SaaS, system integration, entrusted development etc.)

Of course, you will need to revise it to fit your services.  Don't forget to ask a lawyer to review it.

Good luck!